# How to set an absolute position of a view in a ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, view, android-constraintlayout

When I use `getLocationOnScreen` or `getLocationInWindow`, I get the absolute coordinates of a view. Surprisingly for me, the y coordinate of the view takes into account the status bar of the phone, which means that if the view is right at the top of the screen, its y won't be set to 0.

```
profilePic1.getLocationOnScreen(imagePosition1.coor)
```

On the other hand, setting the position of a view with `view.x` and `view.y` isn't absolute, and is relative to the layout, which means that:

```
profilePic1.y = imagePosition1.coor[1]
```

Will place the image at a totally different position, because it will add the height of the status bar to the new position.

My question is: Is it possible to set the coordinates of a view in an absolute matter, while the view is inside a ConstraintLayout? I did find a discussion about that which involves relative layout.
Another option: Is it possible to get the relative coordinates of a layout, instead of the absolute ones (as getLocationOnScreen does) ?

My problem is that I get the positions of views inside my layout and cannot use this information to reposition the views

Answer (score 2):

Oh it was my bad, the answer is easy, it's possible to just use:

```
view.top
view.left
```

to get the relative positions inside the layout. I would like to not delete this question, maybe others can benefit from it showing the difference between absolute screen positions and the relative positions inside the layout

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to set the coordinates of a view in an absolute matter,
> while the view is inside a ConstraintLayout?

Positioning views in `ConstraintLayout` should be done with the constraints; because the `layout_editor_absolutex|y` are only used for design purpose.

But here a couple of ways to position a view in an absolute position within the `ConstraintLayout`:

- Set the view's `topMargin` & `leftMargin` to the absolute position

```
val view = findViewById<...>

val params = view.layoutParams as ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams
params.leftMargin = x // absolute x position
params.topMargin = y // absolute y position
view.requestLayout()
```

- Create a horizontal and vertical guidelines, and set their edges to the y, x absolute positions respectively; then constraint the view to be positioned to the guidelines.

```
val view = findViewById<...>

// Create a horizontal & vertical guidelines and add them to the constraintLayout.
val verticalGL = getGuideline(this, ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.VERTICAL)
val horizontalGL = getGuideline(this, ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.HORIZONTAL)
constraintLayout.addView(verticalGL)
constraintLayout.addView(horizontalGL)

// Set the position of the guidelines.
verticalGL.setGuidelineBegin(x) // absolute x position
horizontalGL.setGuidelineBegin(y) // absolute y position

val set = ConstraintSet()
// Clone the layout's ConstraintSet.
set.clone(constraintLayout)
// Constraint the button to the guideline and apply to the ConstraintSet.
set.connect(view.id, ConstraintSet.START, verticalGL.id, ConstraintSet.START)
set.connect(view.id, ConstraintSet.TOP, horizontalGL.id, ConstraintSet.TOP)
set.applyTo(constraintLayout)


private fun getGuideline(context: Context, orientation: Int): Guideline {
    val guideline = Guideline(context)
    guideline.id = Guideline.generateViewId()
    val lp = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(
        ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    )
    lp.orientation = orientation
    guideline.layoutParams = lp
    return guideline
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming that the view you want to position has no constraints