# How to make a Linear and a Relative Layout share horizontal screen space as percentages?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout, android-layout-weight

How to make a Linear and a Relative Layout share horizontal space as percentages?

The `LinearLayout` on the left needs to have a percentage width of the screen, and the `RelativeLayout` on the right can just take up what remains.  I had this as two `LinearLayout's` and it worked fine because I could use the `layout_weight` attribute, defining width as a percentage, sorta like so:

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_weight=".20"
```

But now I need the layout on the right to be a `RelativeLayout`, and can't figure out how to preserve the desired percentages since `RelativeLayout` does not have a `layout_weight` attribute. What I need looks something like:

[image]

Comment: I believe the weight is LinearLayout attribute, but giving it a try with RelativeLayout it works! Check [this](https://pastebin.com/kJ3ppfgf) out

Comment: It indeed worked.  I think I misunderstood what I read online. If you want to post this solution as an answer I can mark it correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Note: It's better to use [`ConstraintLayout`](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/constraint-layout) now without worring about nested views.

[In RelativeLayout documentation:](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/relative)

> Note: For better performance and tooling support, you should instead build your layout with ConstraintLayout.

Here's the `ConstraintLayout` version:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/teal_700"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.2" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/teal_200"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/view1"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.8" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**To answer for the question conditions if no way to use ConstraintLayout:**

Using `android:layout_weight` in a View that is wrapped in a `RelativeLayout` is prohibited as `RelativeLayout` doesn't provide that attribute for the underlying views (notice attributes start with `layout_` are back to the parent layout which is `RelativeLayout`).

The same way, using `android:layout_weight` in a`RelativeLayout` that doesn't mean that it's back to the `RelativeLayout` itself, but to its parent layout which is already a `LinearLayout`

So, this will work normally either it's `LinearLayout` or a `RelativeLayout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1">
 
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:background="@color/teal_700" />
 
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
        android:background="@color/teal_200">
 
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="This is some text in Relative Layout" />
 
    </RelativeLayout>
 
 
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Better to use a ConstraintLayout as the parent and set layout_constraintWidth_percent to your percentage.

Comment: @Andrew For sure; just updated the answer; I thought the OP is restricted to that

Comment: The reason I switched to RelativeLayout was because I need to position an image with specific x,y coordinates. Advice online was use RelativeLayout. Can do this with ConstraintLayout?

Comment: @Alyoshak pls check the answers here.. Not sure if it can match your case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59493542/how-to-set-an-absolute-position-of-a-view-in-a-constraintlayout